# If I take 6 tickets each with a $\frac{1}{6}$ chance win, am I guarenteed a win?

Tags: probability

Suppose there are a stack of tickets. Each ticket is either a win($\frac{1}{6}$ chance), or not a win($\frac{5}{6}$ chance). So, then suppose I take 6 tickets. Will that guarantee me a win(6$\cdot\frac{1}{6}=1$)? If not, why, and what is my probability that I win by taking those 6 tickets?

Comment: If I toss a coin twice, am I guaranteed a Head?

Comment: @TonyK ah good point! +1

Comment: Even purchasing all tickets but one there is no guarantee to win.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the probability to win after 6 draws is calculated as

$$1 - \left(\frac{5}{6} \right)^6 \approx 0.665$$

What is the probability of **not** winning after 6 times?
The probability is the probability of not winning after the first times the probability of not winning after the second, and so on. Mathematically:

$$P(\textrm{loose all 6}) = \left( \frac{5}{6}\right) ^6$$

Now, winning *at least one* of these times is the complement of the above, and is calculated as 
$$1 - P(\textrm{loose all 6})$$

Comment: Thank you.(can accept answer in 8 minutes)

Comment: I added a more detailed explanation. Hopefully it helps you understand how you should approach similar problems :)

Comment: thank you very much!